# lightbox, colorbox, and fancybox styling

Tags: image, fancybox, lightbox, colorbox

I am about to use any lightbox, colorbox, or fancybox. However, when I read the documentation for all of them, it looks like the images are displayed as an overlay. What I like to do is display the image in a set div above the thumbnails. So, to explain more, here is a sample of html that I like to have

```
<div class="selected-image">
    <!-- This div will be large in dimentions, and will display the selected thumbnail image -->
</div>

<div class="thumbnails">
    <!-- This div will have a list of all the thumbnails available -->
</div>
```

Clicking on any image inside `.thumbnails` will result in changing the image in `.selected-image`

Is it possible to do so? If now, what is the alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: have you seen http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples --> extended functionality --> Thumbnail helper? is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I have seen this, but I do not want the overlay part (where the images come up and appear over the page). I like the effects to be embedded in the page. Maybe I just should make my own. Not worht the customization probably.

Comment: then you don't need a lightbox but a image slider like http://www.pikachoose.com/ or similar